# PGP Whole Disk Encryption status

Tags: disk-encryption, pgp, pgp-desktop

Is there something stored locally on a computer with PGP Whole Disk Encryption that indicates its encryption status? The built-in reporting in PGP Universal Server is unreliable, so I would like to use another tool (something like SSCM) to pull back that indicator and use it as the basis of our reporting.

Edit: We have a mix of PGP Desktop 9.8, 9.9, 9.12, 10.0, and 10.1 in our environment.

Answer (score 1):

I search for the file 'PGPWDE01' present on the C:\ drive, this indicates that the disk volume has been encrypted. Not sure if the file remains present if the system is decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
pgpwde --status
```

should tell you whether or not the drive is currently encrypted.